# Error initializing Hive - java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, installation, hive, initialization

I installed Hive with metastore as Mysql and the database metastore was created successfully in Mysql. Also, I configured the JAVA_HOME in my .bashrc with the correct path,  but when I try to initialize Hive I'm getting a Java eror that I couldn't figure out what's going on and how to solve it.

Here's the error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hive Session ID = 544f6b01-69f3-4f78-b7b9-711bf1dc1fbd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:241)
```

.bashrc config:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HIVE_HOME=/home/eike/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin

Here's the versions I'm using now:

- Hive: 3.1.2
- Ubuntu: 20.04
- Initialize with hiveserver2 but the process didn't appear in the jps
- Configure my hive-site.xml again